# Accesskey in shadow-root element doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, shadow-dom, custom-element, access-keys

Using an accesskey within an element in shadow DOM doesn't trigger in Firefox.

I tested Chrome and Safari on MacOS where it works as expected. Mapping Keys manually via `keydown` or `keyup` event listeners seems complicated, because key mappings differ depending on browser and operating system.

Are there any workarounds or other solutions?

I created simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jk3mrx98/

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const customTextarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    customTextarea.accessKey = 'F';
    customTextarea.innerText = 'Accesskey F'
    shadowRoot.appendChild(customTextarea);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

```html
<textarea accesskey="G">Accesskey G</textarea>
<custom-element></custom-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a bug in Firefox 88 that is fixed in upcoming 89.

Seems that accesskey in shadow root never properly registers in current Firefox stable release (88) and Alt+Shift+F triggers "File" menu there.

But it seems to be fixed in upcoming version: tried your fiddle in Firefox Developer 89.b5 (Aurora release channel) on Windows and both accesskeys works there as expected: Alt+Shift+G focuses "native" textarea, Alt+Shift+F focuses textarea in custom element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested 89.0a1  and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

No answer.

Just showing a different way of writing the constructor:

- You **can** write JS code *before* the `super()` call, but there is no 'this' yet
- you can *chain* on super()

```js
      constructor() {
        const customTextarea = document.createElement('textarea');
        customTextarea.accessKey = 'F';
        customTextarea.innerText = 'Accesskey F';

        super() // sets and returns this scope
          .attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) // sets and returns this.shadowRoot
          .append(customTextarea);
      }
```